# How to add some parameters with spaces with process.start

Tags: vb.net, process.start

i just want to know it there is a way to pass some parameters with process start. I know it can be done with some spaces, but i want to send an adress and full name, both of them have their own spaces, and i need to send them as just 1 parameter.

Comment: [Process.StartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Were you able to figure it out from the link @Plutonix posted or do you need an example?

Comment: I figured it out with jmcilhinney's answer, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you do it if you were typing the commandline into a console window?  You'd wrap each parameter in double quotes, right?  It is exactly the same when using `Process.Start`.  In VB.NET, you denote a literal double quote with two double quotes in a `String`, e.g.

```
Process.Start("myApp.exe", "firstParam ""second param"" thirdParam")
```

That would be equivalent to typing this into a console window:

> myApp.exe firstParam "second param" thirdParam